# How to setup start of days tasks with JIRA

Tags: jira

We use Jira as a ticketing tool. 
I want to setup a start of day (SOD) management which verifies health status of devices. 
Is there any way to achieve this with JIRA? 
JIRA SOD task to be initiated on every working days at 08:30 am and an engineer has to verify and fill the task before 09:00 am. 
We need to get notifications in the task process.
Below is the excel sheet of the requirement

[SOD Requirement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFZTV.jpg)

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this addon for jira:
[HERE](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213072/repeating-issues?hosting=server&tab=overview)

Or you could create a cron job with an API call creating this task.